# Is it possible to read/write to registry in Windows Runtime Component

Tags: windows-runtime, registry, windows-8.1, read-write, winmd

I'm developing a Windows 8.1 application.

Is it possible to read from and write to registry from the Windows Runtime Component (.winmd)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access to the registry from WinRT (8.1/ 10) Application type..
But if you want to save data/ settings.. check the `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings` API

Comment: Unfortunately this is not enough. I need a way to communicate somehow with external windows service and thought that Registry would be the best choice. `ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings` is not accessible from windows service.

Comment: Right, but you can't access to the registry data unless you have a win32 app installed in the same machine to communicate with and access registry .. good luck